# Why UIProgressView set progress not stopping?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5, progress, uiprogressview

I want to show pregress bar animation before to move to the App or Auth VC

By below code it worked fine but the problem it worked for one time only ( the time you start the Application )

So, the question is it stopping issue ? and if it is how to handle it pls??

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)


        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if user == nil {
            // User Signed out

            self.progressive.setProgress(3, animated: true)
            // Before calling asyncAfter perform showing loader or anything you want.


            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                // Your code to execute after a delay of 3 seconds.
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Auth", sender: nil)
            }

        } else {
            // User Signed In

            self.progressive.setProgress(3, animated: true)
            // Before calling asyncAfter perform showing loader or anything you want.

            self.progressive.setProgress(3, animated: true)

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "App", sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What didn't work after starting the app and what do you mean by "stopping issue"? Are you resetting the progress to 0 anywhere?

Comment: @elliott-io exactly this is what I messed in this code... I did it yesterday and it worked

Comment: great! I've added it as an answer for you to accept. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to reset progressView somewhere:

`self.progressive.setProgress(0, animated: false`)

Comment: Thank you ... this exactly what I did and it worked like a charm !!!

Comment: Happy to help, @Let.Simoo!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to reset the progress value to 0

I tried it in viewDidAppear func and it worked!

```
overide viewDidAppear func (_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    self.progressive.progress = 0   

   }
```